# assert_routing with method is giving an error instead of failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, functional-testing, assertions

In my rails 3.2.3 app, I have a topics controller, which is modeled as a resource. I want to write a functional test to verify that post on /topics is a valid route. This should fail first, and then I will add the code to fix it. However, I am getting an error in the routing test, instead of a failure. What am I doing wrong?(Note: If I fix the route in routes.rb, the test passes - just not sure why I am getting an error instead of a failure in the test):

`# topics_controller_test.rb`

```
test 'route exists to create topic' do
  assert_routing({:path => '/topics', :method => 'post'} , { :controller => "topics", :action => "create"}, {}, {}, 'could not route to create topic')
end
```

`# routes.rb`

```
resources :topics, :only => [:new]
```

`# terminal output`

```
$ rake test:functionals
Run options:
```

`# Running tests:`

```
.....E.

Finished tests in 0.373543s, 18.7395 tests/s, 53.5414 assertions/s.

1) Error:
test_route_exists_to_create_topic(TopicsControllerTest):
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches "/topics"
.../gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:633:in `recognize_path'
.../gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:210:in `recognized_request_for'
.../gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:42:in `assert_recognizes'
.../gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:118:in `assert_routing'
        `.../myapp/test/functional/topics_controller_test.rb:25:in block in <class:TopicsControllerTest>'`

>> 7 tests, 20 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Answer (score 1):

The created route in `routes.rb` is different from the route your testing. If you want to route to the `:create` action in the controller, in your `routes.rb` you should use:

```
resources :topics, :only => [:create]
```

See the [routing topic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers) in the RailsGuides.